# Induction due to solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

The electrical energy produce inside the coil due to changing magnetic flux on a coil . The mechanical energy of magnet or coil get converted into electrical energy(law of conservation of energy)  . But , if we use solenoid instead of permanent magnet and change the magnitude of current through solenoid it induces current in the coil.
so my question is , from where this electrical energy come from?
It doesn't get produced by the conversion of mechanical energy.

Answer (score 0):

In effect your have a transformer which is powered by a changing current which might be produced by a generator and hence mechanical energy is a possible source.
Other sources might be sound (microphone), light (photocell), etc.